# UILocalNotification fires immediately instead of at scheduled time

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uilocalnotification

I have an object that stores times in an NSArray as a NSString.  I chose NSString since that's what I end up displaying a lot instead of the NSDate.  I'm trying to setup a UILocalNotification for it.  What I've done is:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"h:mm a";

for (NSString *s in _times) {
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:s];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit)
                                                   fromDate:date];
    NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
    [dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
    [dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
    [dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
    [dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];

    NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];

    NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:itemDate]);
    UILocalNotification *note = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    note.alertAction = thePill.name;
    note.alertBody = thePill.note;
    note.fireDate = itemDate;
    note.timeZone = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] timeZone];

    if (note.fireDate == nil) {
        NSLog(@"nil firedate");
    }

//        note.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;

    NSData *data = [self archivePill:thePill];
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:data forKey:PILL_NOTIFICATION];
    note.userInfo = infoDict;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:note];
}
```

When I NSLog the itemDate time, it is what I want.  At the end of the method, the local notification fires immediately instead at that time.  I'm not sure why since my date is the right time, and I thought I just set the fireDate to that date?  Thanks.

Comment: From the documentation - If the specified value for `fireDate` is nil or is a date in the past, the notification is delivered immediately.

Comment: Check Value of `NSDate *date`, I think it is some past date or may be in in proper format, which makes it `nil`.

Comment: @Crystal: Please print the current data using `[NSDate date]` and compare it with your `itemDate`. I think your `itemDate` may be of the past.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Notification is getting fired immediately.

Answer (score 4):

```
// Fire notification immediately after 1 sec 
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1];
localNotification.alertBody = @"Your alert message";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Answer (score 4):

To fire a notification immediately you should use

```
presentLocalNotificationNow
```

Instead of

```
scheduleLocalNotification
```